# Why does modifying this CALayer within a UITableViewCell cause a nasty graphics glitch?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I set the `cornerRadius` of the `layer` on my image:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedCell")!

    if self.pictunes?.count > 0 {
        // There are some pictunes to show; Create and update the posts
        if self.pictuneImages.count > indexPath.row {

            // We have an image for the user who made the current pictune
            if let pictunerImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIImageView {
                pictunerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 17.5 // Cut it to a circle
                pictunerImageView.image = self.pictunerImages[0]
            }

            // We also have an image for the pictune at the current post
            if let pictuneImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView {
                pictuneImageView.image = self.pictuneImages[indexPath.row]

            }
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        // No pictunes have loaded yet; We probably need more time
        // to load the image and audio assets for some of them
        cell.textLabel!.text = "No Pictunes Available Yet"
        return cell
    }
}
```

But when I scroll I see this nasty background effect:

[image]

How should I get rid of this effect? Clearing the background context didn't help at all. Thanks!

Comment: The gif is too small to really see what you're talking about, but I assume you need to say pictunerImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true after you set the cornerRadius

Comment: the problem he is talking about is the fact that while scrolling up the bottom two corners of the profile image are rounded - if he reaches the top, that changes and the top two corners become rounded.

Comment: ^ Exactly. Sorry the GIF is so small. There's a 2MB limit. I'll try adding `masksToBounds` to `true` as you'd suggested, beyowulf.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thanks, beyowulf. Care to add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set:

```
pictunerImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

after:

```
pictunerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 17.5
```

You could also change this to:

```
pictunerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = pictunerImageView.frame.size.height *0.5
```

In case you ever want to change the size but still want it to be a circle.